# What is $D(n,k)$? (dee-en-kay) /ˈdiːˈɛnˈkeɪ/

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

Is this combinations with repetitions, i.e. ${n+k-1\choose k-1}$ or is this something else entirely? I see this a lot, but with this kind of language no search engine is going to help.

*The edit in the title is for SEO*

---

Example:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k, \textit{where}\; b_k = D(n,k)
$$

The subject of the formula above is some generating function identity.

Comment: It could be nearly anything, though the first good result for it gives $D_n(k)$ as derangements with $k$ fixed points, which seems like a reasonable candidate. Where exactly do you see it?

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish nope, that's not it, I'll edit the question with an example in a moment.

Comment: That is combinations with repetition.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Thanks! if you are certain of it, you can make it an answer. Also, do you have any idea why is it "D"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a stars and bars question.

$$\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^n = (1+x+x^2+ \dots)^n $$
$$= (1+x+x^2+ \dots)(1+x+x^2+ \dots)\dots(1+x+x^2+ \dots)$$

For each $x^k$ term in the final summation, we need to pick terms from each our $n$ "containers" (the parentheses) whose exponents add up to $k$. As we have free choice from $\{0,1,\dots\}$, this corresponds the number of solutions to the system

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n = k \ \ \ \ \textrm{for $x_i \geq 0$}$$

Which is the stars and bars problem, enumerated by 
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

So your answer was correct, $D(n,k) = \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$

$$\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^k$$

---

Kind of strange that they used $D(n,k)$, which suggests derangements to me (and to Google!). Additionally, I think your sum should go to $\infty$, though hopefully that was not an error from the book!

Comment: Yes, that was a copy-paste error. I also forgot the -1. For me Google returns with all kinds of answers, many are related to math, but nothing that would link this to this particular meaning. I'm starting to suspect that D was chosen simply because it follows C in the alphabet...

Comment: That's probably the best explanation, though it's odd they didn't clarify their nonstandard notation.